# In Hybris ,Content page doesn't get synced when change approval status in cms

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Not able to sync content page when i changed the approval status to unapproved.
I reverted back it to "Approved" still page not getting synced.
I compared the dumps in sync job , it's exactly same.
What could be causing the issue?

Comment: Hello, can you add more details to your question please? What version of hybris are you using? Are you trying to synchronize using CMSCockpit or SmartEdit? Maybe this page can give you some clues for SmartEdit : https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/72e0079302514d3e999add5edbd92729.html

Comment: Hi @alain.janinm ,
Thanks for response .
I am trying to sync the content page using cmscokpit.

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting the synchronization is very complicated...

A synchronization is executed using a synchronization cronjob. To find the respective cronjob:

1. go to hmc/backoffice
2. navigate to System/Cronjobs in hmc or System/Background Processes/Cronjobs in backoffice
3. use the types dropdown to restrict the search to "Multithreaded Synchronization"
4. pick the most recent one OR look in log file for this output and search for the code.

> INFO  [Thread-107] (000000RS) [CatalogVersionSyncJob] Sync  'sync powertoolsContentCatalog:Staged->Online' (pk:8796094464500) configured 0 entries for job '000000RS' (pk:8796125823477) schedule medias: 1

This is the cronjob that executed your synchronization. Now it is getting even more tricky:

1. go to the administration tab
2. look for an attribute called "Dump medias"
3. download the media file where attribute Realfilename starts with "sync_dump_"

The downloaded file should contain comma seperated values.

Example:

> 8796256994364;8796256961596;;actions,allDocuments,...,uid,urlLink,visible;;false

The entries represent the following data:

1. the PK of the source item
2. the PK of the target item
3. (timestamp)
4. a list of attributes, that could not be synchronized
5. ?
6. item has been victim to a deadlock

Now you can troubleshoot your synchronization by evaluating source and target items and pending attributes.

Sometimes there is a problem when referencing an item, that does not exist in the target catalog, sometimes a uid is already existing in the target catalog. Sometimes an initial attribute needs change. There are a lot of pitfalls. In this case you can try to use this property to get more details about the exception that is thrown during sync:

```
synchronization.itemcopycreator.stacktraces=true
```

Here is some additional information:
https://www.sap.com/cxworks/article/2589632280/catalog_synchronization#CatalogSynchronization-TroubleshootingFailure