# Hybris Product Sync with legacy false not working

Tags: synchronization, sap-commerce-cloud

We are trying to sync product data from SourceProductCatalog Staged to TargetProductCatalog Staged, however, it is finishing with system errors.

When we turn legacy mode as True the sync works correctly.

There are some direct updates as well on TargetProductCatalog with some other services, is this the reason for sync issue?

We need to perform sync with legacy mode False. Could you please suggest why is this not working?

Hybris version:- 6.6.0.5

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54109462/6509292

The answer is targeted towards content data, but the general idea for product data is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the interceptors/validators which are throwing the error. In legacy mode the service layer is not used. Since you are setting legacy mode to false, the interceptors will be called (like normal modelService.save). This blog could be helpful: https://ecommercecandles.com/sap_hybris_commerce/cms_cockpit_wcms/common_reasons_of_synchronisation_failures
Generally, the sync errors can be analysed by debugging/monitoring:

1. AbstractItemCopyContext : set the property synchronization.itemcopycreator.stacktraces=true (for debugging only). this gives detailed reason, particulary useful if the sync cronjob ends with failure/system error.
2. CatalogVersionSyncJob: this is where the prevalidations are done. Shows erros such as duplicates / version validity errors.
3. Any interceptor/validator that throws error(please share the error logs, this can give a clearer picture).
4. Dumps (in csv): go to the admin tab of the cronjob that failed, and dowload the last csv file. This has the pks of source, target and itemtimestamp along with attributes that failed if any. Try to see if there is any issue with these mentioned attributes